# Angular - Rails values not appearing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm having a strange issue when deploying my app to heroku.

So, there are two ways to create orders. First, whenever a payment is made, an order is automatically created. This is done entirely through Rails. Second, the Orders index view consists of a table which displays all of the orders, with a form to create new orders, which uses Angular. Really, it's more an experiment to practice using Angular.

So, the whole thing works fine in development. All of the orders (created through both methods) show up just fine, along with the corresponding user id, product id, and the total (the amount of money the order would cost).

When I deploy the app, however, I'm having a strange error. Everything works fine, except the totals for orders created with payments aren't showing up. That means, for all orders, the user id as well as product id are showing up, and for orders created with Angular, the order total is showing up. Only for orders created without Angular, the order total isn't appearing.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!!

assets/javascript/angular_app.js

```
var app = angular.module('shop', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('models', ['$resource', function($resource){
    var orders_model = $resource("/orders/:id.json", {id: "@id"});
    var products_model = $resource("/products/:id.json", {id: "@id"});
    var users_model = $resource("/users/:id.json", {id: "@id"});
    var x = {
        orders: orders_model,
        products: products_model,
        users: users_model
    };
    return x;
}]);

app.controller('OrdersCtrl', ['$scope', 'models', function($scope, models){
    $scope.orders = models.orders.query();
    $scope.products = models.products.query();
    $scope.users = models.users.query();
    $scope.addOrder = function(){
        order = models.orders.save($scope.newOrder, function(){
            recent_order = models.orders.get({id: order.id});
            $scope.orders.push(recent_order);
            $scope.newOrder = '';
        });
    }
    $scope.deleteOrder = function(order){
        models.orders.delete(order);
        $scope.orders.splice($scope.orders.indexOf(order), 1);
    }
}]);
```

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?
    respond_to :json, :html

    def index
        @orders = Order.all.to_json(:include => [{:product => {:only => :name}},
                                                 {:user => {:only => :email}}])
        respond_with @orders
    end

    def show
        @order = Order.find(params[:id]).to_json(:include => [{:product => {:only => :name}},
                                                              {:user => {:only => :email}}])
        respond_with @order
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @order = Order.create(order_params)
        @order.product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @order.user = User.find(params[:user_id])  

        OrderMailer.order_confirmation(@order.product, @order.user.email, @order.user.first_name)

        respond_with @order
    end

    def destroy
        respond_with Order.destroy(params[:id])
    end

    protected

    def json_request?
        request.format.json?
    end

    private

    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:product_id, :user_id, :total)
    end
end
```

orders/index.html.erb

```
<div ng-controller="OrdersCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <td>Order ID</td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td></td>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <form ng-submit="addOrder()">
                <td>
                    <span class="form-control" disabled>
                        <%= Order.last.id + 1 %>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" ng-model="newOrder.total">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="newOrder.product_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a product</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="newOrder.user_id" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a user</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.id}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy: '-id':reverse">
            <td>
                {{order.id}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <strong>{{order.total | currency}}</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{order.product.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{order.user.email}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="deleteOrder(order)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  #config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store,
                        (ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
                        {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
                         :passowrd => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
                         :failover => true,
                         :socket_timeout => 1.5,
                         :socket_failure_delay => 0.2
                        }

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)
end
```